# Python selenium unable to locate username element

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create an automated login system for my local library website (http://mcls.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/mclweb) using Python and Selenium. However, my script is unable to find the username box.

The HTML from the website for the username box looks like this

`<input maxlength="30" class="user_name_input" id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text">`

and this is the code I used to find it

```
username = browser.find_element_by_id('j_username')
username.send_keys(u)
```

however, I am getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"j_username"}
```

Am I supposed to use a different function? Or did I use find_element_by_id() wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `INPUT` you are looking for is inside an IFRAME. You will need to switch into it before you will be able to access the username field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login form lies on a frame. You have to switch to the frame.

```
browser.get("http://mcls.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/mclweb")
browser.find_element_by_class_name('loginLink').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.switch_to.frame(1) //login iframe is the second frame in the page
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys(u)
```

Alternative way, in case you want to do without switching to frame:

```
browser.get("http://mcls.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/mclweb/search/patronlogin")
browser.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can also login to that site without using iframe

```html
browser.get("http://mcls.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/login")
browser.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys(u)
```

Comment: @TarunPrakash notify me if it helps